# Inline template of AngularJS does not work with XHTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xhtml, angularjs-templates

I am puzzled about a behavior of inline templates of AngularJS with XHTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="app">
<head>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>

<script type="text/ecmascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.directive('dir',function(){ return{
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'template'
        //template: '<div>Input: <span data-ng-transclude=""></span></div>'
        //if I use template instead of templateUrl, the code works well.
    }; });
    //]]>
</script>
<title>Angular JS template</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template">
    <div>Input: <span data-ng-transclude=""></span></div>
</script>

<input type="text" data-ng-model="input"></input>

<div data-dir="dir"><span style="text-decoration: underline">{{input}}</span></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code works well with the extension of the source `.html` but with `.xhtml`, child nodes of `<div data-dir="dir">` turn empty.

I would be happy if someone could tell me what happens with a change of extensions.

Comment: Hm. Do you absolutely need it to be polyglot markup? The solution to make it work in XHTML is not difficult, but it does make it incompatible with the HTML version.

Comment: Thanks. For some reasons, it would be desirable that my source is machine-readable. Thus, I'm trying to use XHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XHTML is more fidgety with the contents of scripts.

Solution: change all `<` to `&lt;` in the template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="app">
<head>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>

<script type="text/ecmascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.directive('dir',function(){ return{
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'template'
        //template: '<div>Input: <span data-ng-transclude=""></span></div>'
        //if I use template instead of templateUrl, the code works well.
    }; });
    //]]>
</script>
<title>Angular JS template</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template">
    &lt;div>Input: &lt;span data-ng-transclude="">&lt;/span>&lt;/div>
</script>

<input type="text" data-ng-model="input"></input>

<div data-dir="dir"><span style="text-decoration: underline">{{input}}</span></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Or use a CDATA block for the template.

Comment: Thanks. It works completely fine. It was unimaginable for me that the content of `<script>` is required to escape (since it appeared well-formed to me)!

Comment: Yes, that's one very big difference between .xhtml files and .html files: in HTML, <script> (and other elements, such as <style>) is parsed using a plain text parser: its content is simply a chunk of text. While in XHTML, all elements are parsed in the same way, so in your example, the <script>'s content was a <div>.